# Update old Cordova/PhoneGap project with new version of Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app I made a year ago I wish to update. I want to use the latest version of cordova (2.7.0). The existing app runs 1.7.0. Can I simply replace the cordova .js files in my project with the new ones?

I have tried to follow the command line rules of updating a project but I just cannot do it with with my limited knowledge of command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Upgrade Guide of Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS_upgrading_cordova_1_7_0_projects_to_1_8_x) (for iOS).

Comment: Thanks but that only has info for upgrading incrementally, ie 1.7 to 1.8, 1.8 to 1.9 etc not 1.7 to 2.7. Do I need to do these all the way through?

Comment: Yes . Each upgrade procedure is easy. But it is highly recommended that you re-build your app after each version change, to see whether any function breaks or not.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade a Phonegap's Android project:

```
phonegap platform update android
```